# Was the pipe-weed on the set of the Lord of the Rings films real or fake?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, movie, the-lord-of-the-rings, behind-the-scenes, production

Hollywood has been wrestling with the thorny problem of smoking-depiction in films ever since tobacco went out of fashion in the 1990s, replacing on-set smoking with [herbal cigarettes, e-cigs and CGI](https://www.refinery29.com/en-us/2017/02/139108/do-actors-smoke-real-cigarettes-in-movies-tv).

There's a great deal of smoking in the Lord of the Rings films. Some is obviously computer-generated, but at other times what are the cast smoking?

Comment: There is a behind the scenes video where Dominic Monaghan talks about absolutely hating the taste of the pipe smoke

Comment: @fez - That sounds like it would make an excellent answer.

Answer (score 6):

> The actual real-life tobacco that they smoked during filming of The Lord of the Rings was Stokkebye Nougat. Brian Levine, who worked at Stokkebye at the time, supplied them with several pounds of it, and then they called back for more.

This comes from https://pipesmagazine.com/forums/threads/lord-of-the-rings.1413/. So when it wasn't CGI they smoked real tobacco.

Comment: I read that. He certainly seems to be under the impression that it was used on the set, but other interviews disagree

Comment: @Valorum Maybe it was used for other purposes besides the smoking scenes? I mean probably mainly used by cast members that actually smoked. But to go through a few pounds of it and then ask for more it probably got used in other ways.

Comment: My own research suggests that the cast and crew both smoked it and it was also used by the cast in preparation for the shooting scenes, but not necessarily *on the actual set.*

Comment: The props team also made a very large number (hundreds) of prop pipes which they stained by burning real tobacco in the bowl. That would require a considerable amount of tobacco.

Comment: I've found an interview with Brian Levine that you might want to add to your answer; https://rumble.com/vfavw9-pith-helmet-matinee-this-guest-really-dislikes-my-co-host.html

Comment: 1/2 - [This article](https://sopipes.com/index.php?title=A_Pipe-Smoking_Hobbit_From_The_Shire) suggests that the Nougat blend was used by the actors for their own personal use, not by the film's production team' "*One day, while filming atop an active volcano, with an ever-present odor of sulfur, Astin says he smelled “this gorgeous, sweet, pipe tobacco” emanating from a crew member’s pipe. Astin approached the man, Randy Cook, a special-effects supervisor, and they began discussing pipe smoking...*

Comment: 2/2 - *Cook gave Astin some of his tobacco, Mayfair, a French vanilla and nougat-flavored blend that he buys regularly from Gus’ Smoke Shop in Sherman Oaks, California. **During a two-week break in filming, Astin returned to the United States and purchased as much Mayfair as he could legally buy to take back to New Zealand. Soon, some of the other pipe-smoking actors, especially Elijah Wood, began smoking the aromatic Mayfair blend.***

Answer (score 6):

Tobacco was certainly used *on set* by Sean Astin and the other hobbit actors.

> For the pipe-smoking scenes, the actors were presented with the choice of either a mild pipe tobacco or an herbal non-tobacco product. Astin believes that all the hobbit actors in the Fellowship opted for genuine tobacco. “Every hobbit is a good hobbit,” he says, “and a good adult hobbit loves his pipe tobacco!” He claims that none of the other actors, during filming, took pipe smoking as seriously as he did.
>
> <sub><sup>[Pipe and Tobacco Magazine: A Pipe-Smoking Hobbit From The Shire](https://sopipes.com/index.php?title=A_Pipe-Smoking_Hobbit_From_The_Shire)</sup></sub>

No mention is made of the human actors, but in an AMA with Elijah Wood, he mentioned  that Sir Ian had the scent of Old Toby (i.e. tobacco) on him

> **Q. What does Sir Ian Mckellen (Gandalf) smell like?**
>
> **EW:** He smells really good! He smells of a sort of masculine incense. I
> just…I can't put my finger on specifically what notes of the scent are
> there, but there's something very pleasant about the way that he
> smells. Incense definitely comes to mind. What an interesting
> question.
>
> **Q.** And Old Toby
>
> **EW:** That was great.
>
> <sub><sup>[Elijah Wood here. Again. AMA (Ask Me Anything)](http://amatranscripts.com/ama/elijah_wood_2014-02-26.html)</sup></sub>